# Azure web app with on site SQL Server and Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to connect my web app on Azure to our on site SQL Server instance via Windows authentication (not via SQL Server account authentication). Active Directory is already integrated with the on-site AD and therefore all of the users are available there.

My question is, is it possible to hook up an azure web app to an on-site SQL Server via Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to hook up an azure web app to an on-site SQL Server via Windows authentication.

Base on my option, it maybe that we **couldn’t** do that. As we have been limited to do that operation for azure WebApp. There is also another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157623/using-windows-authentication-with-azure-webapp-website?answertab=oldest#tab-top) mentioned that.

If we want to connect to on premise SQL Server, we can use hybrid connections to access on-premises SQL server database in Azure WebApp, more info please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started).

If we want to authenticate the WebApp with local Active Directory, and we have an on-premises secure token service (STS) like Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS), we could use that to federate authentication for our Azure WebApp. More info please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-adfs#test-federated-authentication-for-your-application).

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid connections at this time does not [support AD accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) due to

> because you cannot domain join an App Service worker