# It's posible to apply windows authentication on azure web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have hosted my application on Azure server. And I have created a web app. So now I want to apply on Windows Authentication. It's possible?
How can do that? I have no idea. Any one know then please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31157623/2869093

Comment: @FIL I can also visit this link but I can't understand that's why I have post this issue on here

Comment: so ask the question about what is unclear for you in linked question and answers.

Comment: The problem is for Windows auth the server should be connected to the AD domain AFAIK. And in app service you can't do that. Virtual machines can do that of course. The better is way is to use Azure AD authentication, and then configure your tenant for Seamless SSO, and they can get instantly logged in if they are connected to the domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using windows authentication with Azure WebApp/Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157623/using-windows-authentication-with-azure-webapp-website)