# is it possible to implement kerberos authentication in azure web app?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have an application which is hosted on the on-premises Windows server (IIS) server

now I created a windows server on azure and building a web app for it.where the application needs to  authenticate the user by windows server (DC) using kerbrose protocol but I couldn't find any documentation regarding this from Microsoft's side

Is the above query possible to be implemented in the azure web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to join the VM hosting the website to a domain then as others have mentioned, this isn't possible.

However, doing Kerberos authentication itself within an Azure website isn't particularly difficult, but it does require manual implementation. Windows natively handles all of this for you on domain joined machines and and IIS exposes that functionality. Since you can't domain join you have to manually do all that heavy lifting and request and validate the tickets yourself.

This involves creating a service account in Active Directory and keeping the account password in sync. Once you have that you need to indicate to the browser that it needs to negotiate auth, which is done with the `WWW-Authenticate: negotiate` header on a 401 response. The client, if configured to send tickets, will send a ticket in the `Authorization: Negotiate YII...` request header on a subsequent response. At this point you need to shove that negotiate header and that original service account password into *something* that can validate Kerberos tickets. Windows SSPI will do this for you, but it's a pain. I built a library that'll do this for you: [Kerberos.NET](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET). YMMV with what works best for you.

All of that said, it may be more beneficial to switch over to a more modern authentication mechanism like OAuth/OpenIDConnect/SAML.

Comment: Thank You for answering we are now using Azure AD and have disconnected our AD domain server so will it still be possible? According to this document "https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso" it mentions that it is required to use AD domain server but we do not want to use AD DS as of now.

Comment: You don't have an Active Directory server capable of issuing Kerberos tickets in that case. That's a requirement for Kerberos auth. Options in that case are spin up *AAD DS*, turn your on-premises AD servers back on, or switch over to modern auth.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  Windows Authentication is something for on-premise deployments. For Azure Web Sites Azure Active Directory is clearly the best option. Sync from AD to Azure Active Directory is also quite easy to setup.

If you still want to absolutely use Windows Auth and host your website on Azure, you can create Windows VM and host your website there. You then need to join the VM to your AD. To this, both VMs must be in the same network. So if your VM is on-premise you will need to create an [site-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal).

For more information, follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157623/using-windows-authentication-with-azure-webapp-website) which also discussed about this.

Comment: That's not actually true. Windows Auth is not just for on-premises deployments. It's harder to do, but that doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: If I used Azure ad then karbrose (SSO) auth is possible using azure web app?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways depending on if you have to allow access to users who are associated with a on-premise Active Directory or not.

You should have a look at this service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/

It will offer an Active Directory within Azure where you can domain join your VM to and then using Kerberos as authentication protocol (should work the same way like on prem).

The other option would be to create a new Active Directory within your Virtual Network (via 1 or 2 small Windows Server VMs where you create the AD).

The good thing if you are using Active Directory Domain Services would be that you could extend it to your on-prem Active Directory by synchronizing or federating your on-prem AD.

There are more informations regarding these scenarios here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity

For a Azure App Service - Web App you would connect it to your Azure Active Directory (AAD) and use the hybrid identity model to allow users who originate from an on-prem AD access to it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Hope this helps a bit, it is a rather complicated topic you are digging into.

Comment: we have some limitations we could not use Azure AD. The web app should authenticate users using VM AD is it possible?

Comment: If you create a new AD on a VM, then you can join your webserver (IIS) VM to it (as long as network connectivity exists). 

If you want to use App Services, than you have to connect the new AD  you created on the VMs with you AzureActiveDirectory and connect your App Service app to that AAD. It is not possible to connect apps within App Service directly with an AD server. Only via AAD.